# Different data structures result in huge different size in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I'm trying using Facebook Graph API to get something by python, and there's no problem in my programs.

However, When outputting data to files, I found something strange. I change a structure in output, then my file would be several times bigger.

The original data look like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "20531316728_10154835146021729",
      "created_time": "2016-07-21T16:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "20531316728_10154833920726729",
      "created_time": "2016-07-21T03:02:11+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "20531316728_10154729016861729",
      "created_time": "2016-06-14T00:04:45+0000"
    }
  ]
}
```

I used this before:
(I parsed the data above to a JSON format, and I call it `jsonData`)

```
for tuples in jsonData['data']:
    print(tuples, file=open('test.txt','a'))
```

It will output some strings in files and the output looks like:

```
{'keyA': 'something1', 'keyB': 'something2'}

{'keyA': 'something3', 'keyB': 'something4'}

{'keyA': 'something5', 'keyB': 'something6'}
```

Cause there's no structures, so I changed the `tuples` to `jsonData['data']`,
in order to make the return becoming an array:

```
for tuples in jsonData['data']:
    print(jsonData['data'], file=open('test.txt','a'))
```

The output would be:

```
 [ 
    {'keyA': 'something1', 'keyB': 'something2'},

   {'keyA': 'something3', 'keyB': 'something4'},

   {'keyA': 'something5', 'keyB': 'something6'} ]
```

But the file size is totally different! For instance, I got a **196KB** file by using the `tuples`, and got a **18.9MB** by using the `jsonData['data']`

I used python3, and I tested several times by only changing the statement. 
Are the differences in files common and normal?

Comment: for tuples in jsonData['data']:
    print(jsonData['data'], file=open('test.txt','a')) isn't this rewriting the entire output many times over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between these two `for` loops is that in the second one, you're printing out the entire structure each time the `for` loop body runs.

In the first loop, you are only printing out the current item (well appending it to the output file, but you know that bit already!).

Here's a tiny example that might illuminate it for you.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in x:
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
5
>>> for i in x:
...     print(x)
...
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I'm very glad I could help you!